# Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3c51_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql

I wrote a query and this runs on my local server correctly it has less data,

but when i run this on production server it gets an error - (this has more data around 6GB)

```
Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3c51_0.MYI'; try to repair it
```

Here is my query

```
SELECT   
    `j25_virtuemart_products`.`virtuemart_product_id`,
    `product_name`, 
    `product_unit`,
    `product_s_desc`,
    `file_url_thumb`,
    `virtuemart_custom_id`, 
    `custom_value`   
    FROM 
    `j25_virtuemart_product_customfields`,
    `j25_virtuemart_products`,
    `j25_virtuemart_products_en_gb`,
    `j25_virtuemart_product_medias`,
    `j25_virtuemart_medias`     
    WHERE
    (
    `j25_virtuemart_products`.`virtuemart_product_id`=`j25_virtuemart_products_en_gb`.`virtuemart_product_id`
    AND 
    `j25_virtuemart_products`.`virtuemart_product_id`=`j25_virtuemart_product_customfields`.`virtuemart_product_id`)

AND

    `j25_virtuemart_products`.`virtuemart_product_id`=`j25_virtuemart_product_medias`.`virtuemart_product_id`
    AND 
    `j25_virtuemart_product_medias`.`virtuemart_media_id`=`j25_virtuemart_medias`.`virtuemart_media_id`

    GROUP BY `j25_virtuemart_products`.`virtuemart_product_id`

    LIMIT 0, 1000;
```

Anyone know how to recover from that error - something like otimize this query or any other way
thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Do these steps

Stop mysql service

rename the .myi file to x.old

Start mysql

[REPAIR all the tables in query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/repair-table.html) ,MySQL will rebuild key file

Comment: no mate, site is working corretly
http://tsiopelakos.dev-centiva.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&view=category&virtuemart_category_id=2657&Itemid=134
but this only getting when the above query running you have a idea about optimize this query :)

Comment: one of these tables have a bad key file        `j25_virtuemart_product_customfields`,
    `j25_virtuemart_products`,
    `j25_virtuemart_products_en_gb`,
    `j25_virtuemart_product_medias`,
    `j25_virtuemart_medias` , you have to repair it then the query should work

Comment: thanks man it works nicely, i repaired above tables
ex- REPAIR TABLE cent_virtuemart_products_en_gb
now it working nicely :) great...

Comment: I'm not sure this is good advice. The .myi is in /tmp, meaning it's created dynamically during the query, so it'll likely be gone after the server stops, leaving nothing to rename or repair. Repairing all tables will likely not resolve it either.

Comment: I only needed to run the repair command. I didn't need to rename the file.

Comment: I'd like to note that this happens on Windows too, and the answer is to simply clear out C:\Windows\Temp. Repair doesn't seem necessary, but that might depend on the extent of the corruption.

Comment: This is not a good answer. The problem is more likely one of disk space in /tmp folder. See answer with most upvotes.

Answer (score 58):

The problem is caused by the lack of disk space in /tmp folder.
The /tmp volume is used in queries that require to create temporary tables. These temporary tables are in MyISAM format even if the query is using only tables with InnoDB.

Here are some solutions:

- optimize the query so it will not create temporary tables (rewrite the query, split it in multiple queries, or add proper indexes, analyze the execution plan with [pt-query-digest](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-query-digest.html) and `EXPLAIN <query>`) See this [Percona article about temporary tables](https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/07/17/mysql-disk-space-exhaustion-for-implicit-temporary-tables/).
- optimize MySQL so it will not create temporary tables (sort_buffer_size, join_buffer_size). See: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53201/mysql-creates-temporary-tables-on-disk-how-do-i-stop-it
- make tables smaller. If possible, delete unneeded rows
- use `SELECT table1.col1, table2,col1 ...` instead of `select *` to use only the columns that you need in the query, to generate smaller temp tables
- use data types that take less space
- add more disk space on the volume where /tmp folder resides
- change the temp folder user by mysql by setting the `TMPDIR` environment variable prior to mysqld start-up. Point `TMPDIR` to a folder on a disk volume that has more free space. You can also use `tmpdir` option in `/etc/my.cnf` or `--tmpdir` in the command line of the mysqld service. See: [B.5.3.5 Where MySQL Stores Temporary Files](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/temporary-files.html)

Comment: In our case it was the root (/) folder because our virtual machine has everything in one partition, and the /var/logs/ directory had filled up.  Kudos on the space suggestion though!

Comment: This is the right answer. For innodb especially, since repair tables is not supported. Thank you!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. As stated above, especially for InnoDB tables. I moved my tmp directory for a volume that had 12GB available to one that had 1.3TB available and my query ran no problem after generating a tmp file 19GB in size.

Comment: wow thanks, how we can improve those message?

Comment: Just wondering the first potential solution: 'optimize the query so it will not create temporary tables (rewrite the query, split it in multiple queries, or add proper indexes);, how can we do this?

Comment: I updated my answer with a link to a Percona article that is explains this well. Sometimes it's not possible to avoid, like when using BLOB fields in your query, or sorting.

Answer (score 7):

So many answers are above and the question owner already got the solution as suggested by @Hawili, and a long time has been passed since this problem was raised. But as this a common issue, I wanted to share my experience so that if someone got this issue again due to different reasons then can get solution from here.

Case 1:

Most common reason is that a query is fetching data greater than the size of your /tmp partition. Whenever you get this issue during a query, look at your /tmp folder size. Temporary tables are created and removed automatically, and if available space here gets down to 0 during this query it means either you need to optimize your query or need increase /tmp's partition size.

Note: Sometimes it isn't an individual query: if a combination of heavy queries do this at the same time on the same server then you can get this issue, where normally the individual queries would execute without any error.

Case 2:

In case of a corrupt myisam table where you need to repair, the directory path will be different than /tmp in the error message.

Case 3: (rare case)

Sometimes due to an incorrect table join you can get this error. This is actaully a syntax error but mysql can throw this error instead. You can check details here at below link-

[Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_18b4_0.MYI'; try to repair it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284608/incorrect-key-file-for-table-tmp-sql-18b4-0-myi-try-to-repair-it)

Answer (score 3):

Check the location of your tmp dir, by running `df -h`. Make sure there's enough space to grow the temp file, it could be several gigs.

Edit: If you have enough free space, I'd check to make sure every column you're indexing on or including in the WHERE clause is indexed.

Comment: I know it i want a way for recover this from, something like optimized query or...

Comment: How much free space do you have on /tmp/ ?

Comment: i don't have cpanel access i just running this code via my php file
http://tsiopelakos.dev-centiva.com/index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=2&Itemid=322&txtTitle=&txtIsbn=&txtIsbn13=&txtAuthor=&txtEditor=&txtDfrom=&txtDto=&txtType=&txtPricefrom=&txtPriceto=

Answer (score 0):

Check your database server that you have enough disk space on it. If disks are full this error is displayed. Now, which folders you should look at it depends on your setup.

Answer (score 0):

I used this following command and the error was gone:

`mysqlcheck --all-databases -r #repair`

I got this solution from the [cpanel forum](https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/repair-all-database-in-mysql.69241/)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem to me

Run `df -h` to see if your partition /tmp have enough space

In my case /tmp was a overflow filesystem:

`overflow 1,0M 24K 1000K 3% /tmp`

What happened:

I had some problem here and my partition `/` was full, then Debian distro created a new partition `/tmp` in RAM memor, to use temporarily. This `/tmp` 1MB partition is not big enough for system use.

Solution:
Run the following command to remove this temporary created partition `/tmp`

`sudo umount -l /tmp`

Answer (score -2):

Restart MySQL service using this command line `/etc/init.d/mysqld restart` in terminal.