# Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3f55_0.MYI'; try to repair it

Tags: mysql

Recently the power went out here and my web went down. I'm working on getting everything back up, but am having trouble with the View Tables.

```
Incorrect key file for table '/tmp/#sql_3f55_0.MYI'; try to repair it
```

That is the error I get when I try to view the data in the table.

When I do `df -h` I see:

```
tmpfs   799M(Size)  236K(Used)  799M(Avail) 1%(use%)
```

So if this is the temp folder, size doesn't appear to be an issue.. Any ideas on how to fix this??

Also (less urgent), every few minutes I get blocked access from the Adminer pages and an "Authentication Required" box pops up and asks for a username/password, which isn't the one I normally use. I just close that box and refresh a couple times and I eventually get back in.. Not sure if this is a related issue or not.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11805817/1190388

Comment: Does that apply to a view table though? Also where is the .myi file? @hjpotter92

Comment: Probably `/var/lib/mysql/`

Comment: Only files in there: debian-5.5.flag, ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1, mysql_upgrade_info. There isn't .myi @hjpotter92

Comment: The other suggested answer should be disregarded as it represents distinctly bad/unhelpful info.  You need to check the error log (probably inside /var/log/mysql/).  Also be sure your temp space isn't exhausted *during* the query, only to be immediately freed when the error occurs.