# MySQL create a table for an inner join UNION right join

Tags: mysql, join, union

In my SQL 5.5:

Trying to create a table which is a result of a INNER JOIN of table A & B, and (UNION) RIGHT JOIN of table C & B.

[image: Please see the image for the logic]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME AS (

(SELECT a.column1, b.column2 FROM TABLEA AS a

INNER JOIN TABLEB AS b

ON a.column1 = b.column1)

UNION

(SELECT c.column1, b.column2 FROM TABLEC AS c

RIGHT JOIN TABLEB AS b

ON b.column1 = c.column1)

);
```

Error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT a.column1, b.column2 FROM TABLEA AS a
```

The other attempt:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME AS (

(SELECT a.column1, b.column2 FROM TABLEA AS a

INNER JOIN TABLEB AS b

ON a.column1 = b.column1)

UNION

(SELECT c.column1, b.column2 FROM TABLEC AS c

RIGHT JOIN TABLEB AS b

ON b.column1 = c.column1)

);

Error:

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 11: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UNION
```

Could any guru offer some advice?  Thanks.

Comment: From the Venn diagram, I think you need `LEFT JOIN`, not `RIGHT JOIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following instead:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME AS

(SELECT a.column1, b.column2 FROM TABLEA AS a

INNER JOIN TABLEB AS b

ON a.column1 = b.column1)

UNION

(SELECT c.column1, b.column2 FROM TABLEC AS c

RIGHT JOIN TABLEB AS b

ON b.column1 = c.column1)
```

[**See Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/16245f/1/0)

---

Quoting from the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html)

> ```
> CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] tbl_name
>     [(create_definition,...)]
>     [table_options]
>     [partition_options]
>     [IGNORE | REPLACE]
>     [AS] query_expression
> ```

`query_expression` should not be enclosed by parentheses

Comment: Sadly this doesn't work :/  .  It just says the created table doesn't exist in the following step.  I also tried " CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME (select ...." and it returns the same error message

Comment: Hi  @1000111, thanks for the 2 cents.  I am actually in MySQL 5.5, and if we change the fiddle into MySQL 5.5, the build schema will show unknown error :/

Comment: Strange, works fine for me in 5.5.40 and 5.5.52.  Maybe Fiddle is broken?  Or using an old version of 5.5 with some bug?

Comment: I am not sure @RickJames . Thanks for letting us know.

Comment: What's the exact version of your mysql ? @Chubaka

Comment: http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=72018 -- a fix to `CREATE VIEW ... UNION...` was added to 5.5.39.  Don't know if it affected your `CREATE TABLE ... UNION...`.

Comment: Hi @RickJames , my MySQL is 5.5.49

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TABLE_NAME AS 
(
SELECT S.*
FROM
(
SELECT a.column1, b.column2 FROM TABLEA AS a
INNER JOIN TABLEB AS b ON a.column1 = b.column1
UNION
SELECT c.column1, b.column2 FROM TABLEC AS c
RIGHT JOIN TABLEB AS b ON b.column1 = c.column1
) S
);
```

Comment: Sadly this one doesn't work as well.  It just returns "ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 11: TABLE_NAME doesn't exist".

Comment: Hmm. I tested this an it works fine. You will at least note that the syntax error has gone away.

Comment: Hi @P.Salmon, are you in MySQL 5.5?

Comment: Weird - I have reproduced this error but have not been able to tie it down. I'm not sure that TABLE_NAME is a good table name since information_schema.tables has this as a column and is used as a column name in various system tables. Have you tried with something other than TABLE_NAME?

Comment: Yes I have the same error with other normal, non-information schema table names, and still hit into the same error message.  IMHO, it is a MySQL bug.